# MongoDB - Aggregate deep tree structures

Tags: mongodb

I would like to extract tree graph from my database

This is my structure (which always is always a tree graph)

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b2"), "title" : "a", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b3") } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b3"), "title" : "b", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b4") } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b4"), "title" : "c", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b5") }, { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b6") } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b5"), "title" : "d" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b6"), "title" : "e", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b7") } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b7"), "title" : "f" }
```

I was trying to do something like this

```
db.test3.aggregate([{
     $lookup: {
         from: "test3",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "array"
     }
 }])
```

But then I just receive

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b2"), "title" : "a", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b2"), "title" : "a", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b3") } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b3"), "title" : "b", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b3"), "title" : "b", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b4") } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b4"), "title" : "c", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b4"), "title" : "c", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b5") }, { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b6") } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b5"), "title" : "d", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b5"), "title" : "d" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b6"), "title" : "e", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b6"), "title" : "e", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b7") } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b7"), "title" : "f", "array" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("59490a250f86a4b4e0cb75b7"), "title" : "f" } ] }
```

but this doesnt seems to work as expected

Comment: This does not work recursively. You should read [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) from the MongoDB documentation. Read **all** of it. Properly designed structures and searches have no nesting at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned in above question please try executing following aggregate query in MongoDB shell

```
db.test3.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$array"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $lookup: {
                "from" : "mycoll",
                "localField" : "array._id",
                "foreignField" : "_id",
                "as" : "arr"
            }
        }

    ]



);
```